# remove Django because I am now using VirtualEnv

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I have been playing around with Django and python for a few weeks now and have now decided to bite the bullet and use virtualenv. Obviously I should have done that from the start but due to various config issues, I didn't.

Now when I try to install Django to the virtualenv, it doesn't work. Looking in the Scripts directory, I have pip, easy_install and python but not the django-admin.py file. I have checked a couple of tutorials but no luck.

The output that I get is:

```
(gesplosh) PS C:\Users\nicka_000\documents\coding\websites_go_here\gesplosh>      easy_install Django
Searching for Django
Best match: django 1.7.6
Processing django-1.7.6-py2.7.egg
Adding django 1.7.6 to easy-install.pth file

Using   c:\users\nicka_000\documents\coding\websites_go_here\gesplosh\lib\site-    packages\django-1.7.6-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for Django
Finished processing dependencies for Django
 (gesplosh) PS       C:\Users\nicka_000\documents\coding\websites_go_here\gesplosh> dir


Directory: C:\Users\nicka_000\documents\coding\websites_go_here\gesplosh


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----        02/12/2014     08:49            Include
d----        18/03/2015     10:22            Lib
d----        18/03/2015     10:23            Scripts
```

and when i go into the Scripts directory I have this:

```
C:\Users\nicka_000\documents\coding\websites_go_here\gesplosh\Scripts


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---        18/03/2015     10:23       2379 activate
-a---        18/03/2015     10:23        596 activate.bat
-a---        18/03/2015     10:23       8252 activate.ps1
-a---        18/03/2015     10:23       1129 activate_this.py
-a---        18/03/2015     10:23        348 deactivate.bat
-a---        18/03/2015     10:22      95138 easy_install-2.7.exe
-a---        18/03/2015     10:22      95138 easy_install.exe 
-a---        18/03/2015     10:23      95110 pip.exe 
-a---        18/03/2015     10:23      95110 pip2.7.exe
-a---        18/03/2015     10:23      95110 pip2.exe
-a---        18/03/2015     10:22      26624 python.exe
-a---        18/03/2015     10:22      27648 pythonw.exe
```

It feels like I have missed a step to get Django installed in my virtual env but none of the tutorials I have looked at seem to need to do anything else. What do I need to do in order to get Django installed in my virtual directory?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are working in a virtualenv, you should use `pip` to install packages. So, rather than easy_install, just do:

`pip install django`

This should install Django to the virtualenv instead of system wide and you should be all set.

Comment: thanks - do i need to do anything to close the question?

Comment: There should be a little checkmark to the left of my answer, click on it to "Accept" this answer as correct. Thanks!